# Why is this MySQL query "using where" instead of "using index"?

Tags: mysql, index, performance, explain, query-performance

Could you help me with this query, please?

```
SELECT p.patid, MAX(c1.eventdate) as eventdate 
from patient as p 
left join op_adv_effects._clinical as c1 on p.patid = c1.patid 
left join op_adv_effects._additional as a1 on c1.patid = a1.patid 
where c1.adid <> 0 
and c1.adid = a1.adid 
and a1.enttype = 13 
and a1.data3 is not null 
and c1.eventdate < p.case_index
group by p.patid
```

Here is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 3 tables:

**`patient`**

```
   CREATE TABLE `patient` (  
  `patid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `case_index` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',  
  `pracid` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `first_registration_date` date DEFAULT NULL,  
  `transfer_out_date` date DEFAULT NULL,  
  `transfer_out_reason` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,  
  `last_collection_date` date DEFAULT NULL,  
  `deathdate` date DEFAULT NULL,  
  `birth_year` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `gender` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_cs,  
  `marital_in_gprd` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_cs,  
  `strategic_health_authority` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_cs,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`patid`,`case_index`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs
```

**`_clinical`**

```
  CREATE TABLE `_clinical` (  
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `patid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `eventdate` date DEFAULT NULL,  
  `sysdate` date DEFAULT NULL,  
  `constype` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `consid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `medcode` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `staffid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `textid` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,  
  `episode` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `enttype` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `adid` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `idx_clin_eventdate_medcode` (`patid`,`eventdate`,`medcode`),  
  KEY `idx_clin_eventdate_adid` (`patid`,`eventdate`,`adid`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62407536 
  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1   COLLATE=latin1_general_cs
```

**`_additional`**

```
    CREATE TABLE `_additional` (  
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `patid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `enttype` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `adid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `data1` decimal(8,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `data2` decimal(8,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `data3` decimal(8,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `data4` decimal(8,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `data5` decimal(8,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `data6` decimal(8,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `data7` decimal(8,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `idx_add_enttype_adid_data1` (`patid`,`enttype`,`adid`,`data1`),  
  KEY `idx_add_enttype_adid_data3` (`patid`,`enttype`,`adid`,`data3`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13556604 
  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1   COLLATE=latin1_general_cs
```

"explain" returns the following:

[image: Explain of the query]

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************  
           id: 1  
  select_type: SIMPLE  
        table: p  
         type: index  
possible_keys: PRIMARY  
          key: PRIMARY  
      key_len: 7  
          ref: NULL  
         rows: 182939  
        Extra: Using index  
*************************** 2. row ***************************  
           id: 1  
  select_type: SIMPLE  
        table: c1  
         type: ref  
possible_keys: idx_clin_eventdate_medcode,idx_clin_eventdate_adid  
          key: idx_clin_eventdate_adid  
      key_len: 4  
          ref: gprd_opadveff_extra_elisa.p.patid  
         rows: 166  
        Extra: Using where; Using index  
*************************** 3. row ***************************  
           id: 1  
  select_type: SIMPLE  
        table: a1  
         type: ref  
possible_keys: idx_add_enttype_adid_data1,idx_add_enttype_adid_data3  
          key: idx_add_enttype_adid_data1  
      key_len: 8  
          ref: gprd_opadveff_extra_elisa.p.patid,const,op_adv_effects.c1.adid  
         rows: 1  
        Extra: Using where
```

Why is it not using:

- on `c1` the whole index `(patid,eventdate,adid)`, but only `patid` (see ref column)?
- on `a1` the correct index `idx_add_enttype_adid_data3`?

Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: Please edit the question and replace the "relevant parts" with the output of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for the 3 tables. The whole picture is much more useful. It would be good if you also provided the text version of the explain (you can use `EXPLAIN SELECT ....  \G` in the command line, I think there's similar in phpmyadmin)

Comment: Yes, this is much better.

Comment: Last question(s). How many different patient ids are there in the c1 table? And is there another table with `patid` as the primary key?

Comment: select count(distinct patid) from _clinical -> 174164. Only the table patient has patid in the PK in the source db (op_adv_effects). I have to produce a destination db (gprd_opadveff_extra_elisa) with calculated data: in this second db many intermediate tables will contain patid in the PK. In particular, the query under investigation is part of a more complicated query where I have to provide also the a1.data3 corresponding to the MAX(c1.eventdate) for each patid. Thank you

Comment: Failure to use idx_add_enttype_adid_data3 -- file a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com .